# Is it possible to acces information from an entry inside of a definition and use it outside of the definition

Tags: function, tkinter

The goal is to make a program where you first get to chose if you want to anwser question 1 or 2. As you make your choice a secondary window appears where you enter your anwser. Because of this information is obtained through a entry in a secondary window. The entry is therefore defined inside of a definition(atleast in my code). Because of this the program will not launch as the "vm" in "`print(vm)`" is not initially deffined.

Is there maybe a way of delaying the print action until "vm" is defined?

(only a part of the code)

```
def open2():
    global top2
    top2 = tk.Toplevel()
    top2.title('second window')
    lbl2 = tk.Label(top2, text='question 1')
    lbl2.place(y=50, x=150)
    global ent2
    ent2 = tk.Entry(top2, bd=0, bg=rgb_hack((255, 255, 255)))
    ent2.place(y=100, x=150)
    top2.config(bg=rgb_hack((163, 236, 165)))
    top2.geometry("450x250")
    btnbm = tk.Button(top2, text='ok', command=entbm).pack()
    root.withdraw()

def entbm():
    global vm
    vm = (ent2.get())
    vm = vm.replace(' ', '').lower()
    top2.destroy()
    return vm

print(vm)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('first window')
root.geometry("450x250")
root.config(bg=rgb_hack((163, 236, 165)))
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="to question 1", command=open1, bd=0, height=2, width=20, bg=rgb_hack((255, 255, 255)))
btn1.place(y=50, x=150)
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="to question 2", command=open2, bd=0, height=2, width=20, bg=rgb_hack((255, 255, 255)))
btn2.place(y=100, x=150)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Based on the posted code, move `print(vm)` into `entbm()`.